# Issue connecting to play game using game center

Tags: ios, connection, game-center, multiplayer

I am facing the issue of `Multiplayer Invitation endless Processing` below is the detail.

```
open func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept inviteToAccept: GKInvite) {
    print("player is \(player) \nInvite is \(inviteToAccept)")
    EGC.guestPlayerIdentifier = player.playerID

    guard let gkmv = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: inviteToAccept) else {
        EGCError.error("GKMatchmakerViewController invite to accept nil").errorCall()
        return
    }

    gkmv.matchmakerDelegate = self

    var delegeteParent:UIViewController? = EGC.delegate.parent

    if delegeteParent == nil {
        delegeteParent = EGC.delegate
    }

    delegeteParent!.present(gkmv, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

On average only `1` out of `5` tries would they be able to connect & play a
full match.

If one of them invited another who had the `game` open on his phone
he would get the invite and `game` would start but for the other, the `game`
would be blank or endlessly processing. However, if the invited didn't
have his `game` opened already it seemed to work more often. any help would be appreciated

[image].

Comment: can you show us the code where you are handling all incoming game requests ?

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary code added. please take a look

Comment: You need to `present` the `gkmv ` on `main thread` if I am not wrong.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary thanks, i will do the same. I will love to hear more about this issue. if you have some other findings please do share.